# How to get a cell reference programatically

Tags: excel

I want to use a specific range reference programmatically to sum (next 25 cells), for which I'm using `OFFSET()`, which requires a cell reference. However, most lookup functions return indexes, or values, not cell references, so I have to use `INDEX()`.

I find it a bit ridiculous that I have to do this just to find the cell reference of a cell programatically:

> INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0), 1)

Is there a better way to get a cell reference programmatically?

The whole thing looks like:

> =SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0), 1), 0, 1, 25, 1))

Comment: Would you be able to use `ADDRESS()` at all?

Comment: `Match()` returns the matched cell's Row, where you have specified what column to search... you can use something like `ADDRESS(MATCH(C2,A:A,0),1)` and utilize that in your offset.

Comment: @BruceWayne @Cyril `OFFSET()` doesn't accept the output of `ADDRESS()`, I have to do `INDIRECT()` first. It gets specially messy when using cells from another sheet.

Comment: @FelipeC that whole volatile function thing... i was thinking `indirect()` was also volatile and not usable with `offset()`; can never keep some of those straight without just plug-n-chug techniques.  last i remembered, `index()` was also volatile and wasn't able to be used in an offset, but i can do that now, so probably changed in one of the newer excel versions

Answer (score 0):

You will want to utilize multiple `Match()` and their offsets... see:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)-1,0):OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)+24,0))
```

---

Broken down:

- First cell in your range to sum in column 1 (A), have to subtract 1 from it so you're using your actual match reference:

  OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)-1,0)
- Final cell in your range to sum in column 1 (A), have to subtract 1 from the desired offset (25) similar to the first cell:

  OFFSET(A1,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)+24,0)
- You can then sum between the offsets

Answer (score 0):

It may seem ridiculous to you but the best non-volatile option is a pair of INDEX/MATCH functions that define the start and stop of your sum range in column B and dispense of OFFSET altogether.

```
=sum(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0)+24))
```

Comment: That is an interesting way of solving the problem, but it's even more complex than what I started with. The reason I want the cell reference is to simplify the formula.